# Access files from internet to internal server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, storage

I have an external IP pointing to it and I can mstsc (access via RDP) to it but I can't access it via

```
\\IPADDRESS
```

Any ideas?

Comment: So you are asking how to access SMB over the Internet?  You really should be running that within a VPN or something.  SMB doesn't work all that well through NAT, and when crossing the Internet, you will almost certainly go through a couple devices performing NAT.  If you really want to access the file server over the Internet, without a VPN, then look at Webdav.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Openvpn.net and learn. Great VPN software.

Trying to share a SMB over NAT is as mentioned a bad idea. I will guess your trying to share files between two servers overs the Internet? Or is it between Users?

If your using windows server use **Routing and Remote Access Services**. Its built in. (though I would take a Cisco or Juniper setup over it that any day)

Link to help
http://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2010/10/how-to-install-vpn-on-windows-server-2008-r2/

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't have the required ports open in your firewall, which isn't advised. Accessing the file system of the server over the internet via SMB is a very risky proposition.